# SQL Oracle Query: Can this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select the most recent entries of a database table which contains multiple rows with the same product numbers (but a different date).
In this particular case, I want to filter the `TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS` table by `PRODUCT_NUMBER`s which occur at least five times in the table, and out of that subset, I want to retrieve the rows with the most recent `SAVEDATE` for each prdocut number

I managed to create such a query, but with three sub queries T1, T2, T3. I have the feeling It can be done with only two tables and the inner join is not needed. But it took many hours to create this, because it was hard to translate the script from MySQL to Oracle.

Is it possible to optimize the following query so less sub queries are required?

```
SELECT * FROM
messfeld.TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS T1
JOIN
(
  SELECT PRODUCT_NUMBER, COUNT(*)
  FROM messfeld.TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS 
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_NUMBER
  HAVING COUNT(*)>5
) T2
ON T1.PRODUCT_NUMBER=T2.PRODUCT_NUMBER
WHERE T1.SAVEDATE BETWEEN '27-AUG-14' AND '28-AUG-14' AND
(T1.SAVEDATE, T1.PRODUCT_NUMBER) IN 
(
SELECT MAX(T3.SAVEDATE), T3.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
FROM messfeld.TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS T3
WHERE
T2.PRODUCT_NUMBER=T3.PRODUCT_NUMBER
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NUMBER
);
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results? Or even better, create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Hmm, are you only looking at records between the two specified dates; or all records but where the most recent is between those dates?

Comment: This is a good question. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the product number and date, you could simplify the current approach quite a bit; as you suspected you're hitting the table once more than you need to, and could replace the joins with an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NUMBER, MAX(SAVEDATE)
FROM TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS
WHERE PRODUCT_NUMBER IN (
  SELECT PRODUCT_NUMBER
  FROM TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS 
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_NUMBER
  HAVING COUNT(*)>5
)
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NUMBER;
```

But if you have other columns then you need to make it more complicated again.

You can use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) to prevent having to hit the table multiple times or do any joins:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NUMBER, SAVEDATE --, other columns
FROM (
  SELECT T.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.PRODUCT_NUMBER
      ORDER BY T.SAVEDATE DESC) AS RN,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T.PRODUCT_NUMBER) AS CNT
  FROM TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS T
  WHERE T.SAVEDATE BETWEEN DATE '2014-08-27' AND DATE '2014-08-28'
)
WHERE CNT > 5
AND RN = 1;
```

The inner query gets all the columns from the base table, and adds pseudocolumns based on the analytic functions. `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns a value to each row for a particular product, with the most recent date as number 1 (via the `ORDER BY ... DESC`). You could also consider `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`, particularly if you might have ties and want to show all rows when a tie does occur. `COUNT(*)` counts the rows for each product.

The outer query then filters that to only have the products that have a count greater than five; and also to only get the row ranked first, which is the most recent.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71c1c/10) with your original query and this one for the same data.

I've also switched to using date literals; you should at least be using `TO_DATE` with an explicit format mask rather than rely on the session NLS settings. Also note thet `BETWEEN` in inclusive, so this (and your original) would pick up midnight on the 28th; you might want to use:

```
  WHERE T.SAVEDATE >= DATE '2014-08-27'
  AND T.SAVEDATE < DATE '2014-08-28'
```

.. or if you are trying to include all records from both days then `< DATE '2014-08-29'`. I assume they have times, otherwise five records for the same date would look the same and you'd need some other way to decide which is 'latest'.

Comment: Thank you Alex. It seems that your query is better than mine. I used my query here in my company with our Oracle Database and I got 5 Results. With your query and the same date I get 8 results. For a particular reason, there is a difference. I will check a little bit, but anyway, I will use your query.
I can learn a lot, especially because I am a beginner to SQL. Thanks again!

Comment: @Burkhard - I asked in a comment where the date restriction should be applied; would that account for the difference in the results? It's simple to change but not sure which you actually want. Thorsten has a third interpretation too, so please clarify what the selection criteria are.

Comment: @Alex Poole this is really a great answer (mine was "in prep' without seeing yours, otherwise I would have just commented). Just one thing, don't you need DESC in the row number sorting? (the most recent entries)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - yes indeed, thanks; guess I deserved to have an error after pointing out yours <grin>

Answer (score 2):

Unless using a quite old Oracle version you can use the analytic form of `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to arrive at the wanted result I believe. Try this:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            TNMR.*
          , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TNMR.PRODUCT_NUMBER) AS CN
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TNMR.PRODUCT_NUMBER
                               ORDER BY TNMR.SAVEDATE DESC) AS RN
      FROM messfeld.TKP_NOISE_MOTOR_RESULTS TNMR
      ) T1
WHERE T1.CN >= 5 AND T1.RN = 1
AND T1.SAVEDATE BETWEEN '27-AUG-14' AND '28-AUG-14'
;
```

However I really would not recommend dd-mmm-yy as date literals, and I never use `BETWEEN` for date ranges and would use this instead:

```
AND T1.SAVEDATE >= to_date('27-08-2014','dd-mmm-yyyy') 
AND T1.SAVEDATE < to_date('28-08-2014','dd-mmm-yyyy') + 1 -- 1 day added
```

---

FOOTNOTE
"select *" is a convenience only, it is used above only to abbreviate and/or because the details are unknown. Please fully specify the selection clause.

Comment: You can't combine a plain `*` with other columns in the inner query; you need to alias the table and prefix it, e.g. `T.*, COUNT...`. Otherwise you'll get ORA-00923.

Comment: "*quite old Oracle version*" - window functions (aka "analytical" functions) are available since Oracle 8i.

Comment: @Alex Poole - I shall add my usual footnote to this. I agree you are right - but...

Comment: @Used_By_Already - but what? [Your code errors](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71c1c/6); but it's [easily fixable with an alias](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71c1c/5). (I'm not complaining about the `*` itself here - it makes sense in a subquery. In the outer query you might not want the RN and CN columns but that's a detail, and wasn't my point *8-)

Comment: blimey, you guys are tough, I do actually mean "select *" is a convenience, and that the reader needs to do something. But, I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are searching for all products for which

- exist more than five records
- exists at least one record on the 27th or 28th of August.

Of these you want to take the newest record found within that date range.

So select all products having more than 5 records (as you already do) and determine the most recent save date in the date range using a case construct.

```
select *
from messfeld.tkp_noise_motor_results 
where (product_number, savedate) in
(
  select
    product_number, 
    max(case when to_char(savedate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') in ('27-08-2014', '28-08-2014') then savedate end)
  from messfeld.tkp_noise_motor_results 
  group by product_number
  having count(*) > 5 
  -- the next line is not really needed. Use it if you find it more readable
  and max(case when to_char(savedate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') in ('27-08-2014', '28-08-2014') then savedate end) is not null
);
```